# Read router manufacturer, model and chipset

Tags: python, wifi, router, scapy, chipset

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
ap_set = set()
def PacketHandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and (pkt.type, pkt.subtype) == (0, 0) and pkt.addr2                    not in ap_set:
        ap_set.add(pkt.addr2)
        print "AP MAC: {} with SSID {}".format(pkt.addr2, pkt,info)
sniff(iface="mon0", prn=PacketHandler)
```

I want to create an application that lists all available WiFi access points and their model and chipset information. Is this possible? If so, can I do it with `scapy` or do I need a different import?

Comment: *"Python is not my native language"* I don't think it is anyone's native language :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use `iwlist` to list all the available access points? I'm not sure if it's possible to get the model and chipset information from a remote router regardless of being connected to it or now. Anyway, to get at least some info, you could try the [OS fingerprinting](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html) functionality of the `nmap` tool.

If you're set on Python, I suppose figuring out how either of the tools above do it could do the trick.

Comment: In order to use nmap I have to be connected to the access point Im scanning. I want to do a scan of all visible access points nearby and read their model and chipset without being connected to them.

Comment: I somehow doubt that's possible since accessing information such as the router manufacturer without having access to the router would be considered a security flaw: information disclosure.